# Writing a custom function for ggplot: How to avoid overriding `theme()` settings when adding external themes

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, themes

I want avoid repeating code for plotting, so I wrote a simple function for `ggplot`. I specify several preferences using `theme()`. However, if I want to apply an external theme (e.g., `theme_bw()`), it overrides my specific `theme()` preferences. *If* I had been writing code **not** in a user defined function, the solution would've been simple: rearrange the structure of `ggplot`'s code so that `theme_bw()` comes before `theme()`. But I don't know how to address this in the case of a custom function.

### Data

```r
df <- 
  data.frame(
    x_names = c("asia", "europe", "america", "africa", "australia"),
    y_values = 1:5
  )

##     x_names y_values
## 1      asia        1
## 2    europe        2
## 3   america        3
## 4    africa        4
## 5 australia        5
```

### Function for plotting

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_from_data <- function(data_input, x_col, y_col) {
  
  p_barplot <- 
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = {{ x_col }}, y = {{ y_col }}, fill = as_factor({{ x_col}} ))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(caption = "caption blah") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14),    ## I have a bunch
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0),     ## of preferences
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),                       ## I set up using
          legend.title = element_blank(),                       ## `theme()`
          panel.grid  = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 8),
          legend.position = "none")
  
  return(p_barplot)
  
}
```

### Plotting using the function

```r
p <- plot_from_data(data_input = df,
               x_col = x_names,
               y_col = y_values)

p
```

[image: just_p]

### But let's say I want to add a theme

```r
p + theme_bw()
```

[image: p_w_theme_bw]

Yikes. This is undesired. I didn't want a legend and didn't want x axis title, etc.
So one solution is to go back to `plot_from_data`'s code and add `theme_bw()` ***before*** `theme()`. But this is not a good solution because I want to be able to flexibly apply different themes *on top of* `plot_from_data`'s plot, without having to re-edit the function's code for each plot.

Another solution would be to keep both `bw_theme()` and `theme()` outside of `plot_from_data`. Then, for each plot I generate I'd add `p` + `theme_bw()` + `theme(...)`. But this is undesired as well because `theme()` is full of preferences I don't want to repeat each time.

How could I solve this? One idea I have, but don't know how to apply, is having a "theme placeholder" within `plot_from_data`, before `theme()`. Something like:

```r
plot_from_data <- function(data_input, x_col, y_col) {
  
  p_barplot <- 
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = {{ x_col }}, y = {{ y_col }}, fill = as_factor({{ x_col}} ))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(caption = "caption blah") +
    ***theme_placeholder*** + ##################################  <----------------------- here
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.grid  = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 8),
          legend.position = "none")
  
  return(p_barplot)
  
}
```

However, I don't know how to make this flexible enough. One problem I can immediately think of is with `ggthemes` library that sometimes requires two components for a theme (e.g., `theme_economist()` and `scale_color_economist()`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a conditional value to your function so that if the value is equal to 1, then add a specific theme and so on.

Comment: call `theme_set(theme_bw())` before you call your custom plotting function (see [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme_get.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an optional theme as an argument to the function. If you need to add a color scale, you can tack this on after the function runs, since the scale function won't override any `theme` elements.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

plot_from_data <- function(data_input, x_col, y_col, my_theme=NULL) {
  
  my_theme = list(my_theme)
  
  p_barplot <- ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = {{ x_col }}, y = {{ y_col }}, fill = as_factor({{ x_col}} ))) +
    geom_col() +
    labs(caption = "caption blah") +
    my_theme +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.grid  = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 8),
          legend.position = "none")
  
  return(p_barplot)
  
}

plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width)
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, theme_bw())
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, theme_economist()) + 
  scale_fill_economist()
```

[image]

You could even add the scale function in the `my_theme` argument if you enter the argument as a list:

```
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, 
               list(theme_economist(), scale_fill_economist())
```

Another option (maybe overkill) would be to allow the user to optionally add the name of a fill scale as a string. For example:

```
  plot_from_data <- function(data_input, x_col, y_col, my_theme=NULL, my_fill_scale=NULL) {

  
  my_theme = list(my_theme)
  
  p_barplot <- ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = {{ x_col }}, y = {{ y_col }}, fill = as_factor({{ x_col}} ))) +
    geom_col() +
    labs(caption = "caption blah") +
    my_theme +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.grid  = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 8),
          legend.position = "none")
  
  if(!is.null(my_fill_scale)) {
    p_barplot = p_barplot + 
      match.fun(paste0("scale_fill_", my_fill_scale))()
  }
  
  return(p_barplot)
  
}

plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, theme_economist())
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, theme_economist(), "economist")
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, theme_economist(), "fivethirtyeight")
```

[image]

Going even further, you could use the same trick to enter the theme as a string and also set up the function to automatically pick the corresponding scale, where appropriate:

```
plot_from_data <- function(data_input, x_col, y_col, my_theme=NULL, my_fill_scale=NULL) {
  
  p <- ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x ={{ x_col }}, y={{ y_col }}, fill=as_factor({{ x_col}} ))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(caption = "caption blah")
  
  if(!is.null(my_theme)) {
    p = p + match.fun(paste0("theme_", my_theme))()
  }
  
  p = p + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14),
                axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0),
                axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                legend.title = element_blank(),
                panel.grid  = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 8),
                legend.position = "none")
  
  if(!is.null(my_fill_scale)) {
    p = p + 
      match.fun(paste0("scale_fill_", my_fill_scale))()
  }
  
  if(!is.null(my_theme)) {
    if(my_theme %in% c("economist","fivethirtyeight","few") & 
       is.null(my_fill_scale)) {
      p = p + match.fun(paste0("scale_fill_", my_theme))()
    }
  }
  
  return(p)
}

plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, "economist")
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, "economist", "viridis_d") 
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, "economist", "few") 
plot_from_data(iris, Species, Petal.Width, "fivethirtyeight")
```

[image]